# Pass TWO JavaScript variables to PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, variables, global-variables

Im trying to pass two JavaScript variables to PHP variables.

```
function myFunction(){
  var one = 'one';
  var two = 'two';
}
```

After doing my research, I have pretty much come to the conclusion I am going to have to use AJAX, something like

```
window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?one=" + one;
window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?two=" + two;
```

But Im having trouble picking up the variable in PHP using

```
$_GET['one']
$_GET['two']
```

Im also confused as to whether I am calling the php script twice.  Is there a working way to pass two variables?  I have found several ways to pass one but none to pass two.

Comment: `window.location.href` is a browser redirection, not an AJAX call. Since you have tagged jquery-ajax, [start reading here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Your call would be something like `$.get('myphpfile.php?one=one&two=two'...)`, but there's more to it than that...

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to how you're having trouble picking up a variable? Any errors you can tell us? perhaps to an `isset($_GET['one'])` and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will send the two variables in a single request

```
window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?one=" + one + "&two=" + two;
```

but window.location.href is not an AJAX request.  Calling the above code will cause the browser location to change to myphpfile.php.

See [this page](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript) for how to get started with AJAX, or alternatively you could consider using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: This will correctly call the PHP script only once, but it is not an AJAX call. As @MichaelBerkowski recommended, have a look at [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks, Im a bit of a beginner with JQuery so I will have to wait until I have found my way around it.  I would prefer not to have the page redirect but I can work with it. Needed a fast solution and I got one, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to "fire and forget" those variables, you don't need AJAX. Common way (not elegant,  but working) is using hidden frame:

```
<iframe id="MyFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Then in your code:

```
function myFunction(){
    var one = 'one';
    var two = 'two';
    document.getElementById("MyFrame").src = "myphpfile.php?one=" + encodeURIComponent(one) + "&two=" + encodeURIComponent(two);
}
```

This will cause PHP to receive the request, however if you want to read and parse the result, you better use "real" AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to send variables to another page then use:

```
           window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?one=" + one + "&two=" + two;
```

if you want ajax request:

```
            $.ajax({
               url: "myphpfile.php",
               method: 'get',
               data : {one:"one",two:"two"},
              success:function() {
              alert("hi to all");
              });
```

Comment: You have not added the parameters one and two into the Ajax call.

Comment: Will this ajax request run the PHP file or just save the date to be collected when the script is called?  I absolutely know nothing about AJAX and read that I needed to use it to get the data from client side to server side.

Comment: ajax will take data from php page then in success option render data on the current page.